# SAP Fiori Launchpad - System News style popup

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

On the ONE Support Launchpad there is a small popover 'System News' section at the bottom left where notification info is clear to see.

I have never seen this before or within any fiori documentation etc...

Does anyone have any idea if this is a useable component or whether it is likely to be a custom SAP piece used just on the ONE Support Launchpad?

Or perhaps an alternative method of displaying notifications to users for the Launchpad?

Fiori Launchpad - System News Notification:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this ONE support launchpad is a pretty custom made FLP (and it pretty much looks like the standard FLP). Thus, this system message feature is also custom made. I would love to this in feature also in the standard FLP as this seems to be an important feature for clients...

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong - and I would be so happy to be wrong :-)

Comment: I too have the impression it is a custom job, but I'm also hoping there that it is available. So for I've found nothing in the fiori admin side, theme designer and the rest.